# How to deal with checkbox using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

i want to scrape a page with checkboxes with no **id**, they have the same name and just the values are differents.

```
<div class="mvNavLk">
    <form class="jsExpSCCategories" method="post" name="ExpressSCCategories" action="actionTest.html">
        <ul class="mvSrcLk">
            <li>
                <label class="mvNavSel mvNavLvl1">
                    First
                    <input type="checkbox" value="firstValue" name="selectedNavigationCategoryPath">
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="mvNavSel mvNavLvl1">
                    Second
                    <input type="checkbox" value="secondValue" name="selectedNavigationCategoryPath">
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to set? what element you want to access?

Comment: @theRoot i want to set the value for example "firstValue" in check box,

Comment: you want to set the value or click the check box with value firstValue

Comment: i want to click the check box with value firstValue,

Comment: It seems that you are using the wrong method.
   select=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("selectedNavigationCategoryPath")

from HTML snippet, it looks like you should use 'find_element_by_name' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".mvSrcLk>li:nth-child(1)>label.mvNavSel.mvNavLvl1").click();
```

hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, so we doesn't need to value?

Answer (score 1):

Hi please do it like below **Note** this example is in java

```
// take check boxes with same name inside the list 
List<WebElement> myCheckBox = driver.findElements(By.name("selectedNavigationCategoryPath"));

// now on the basis of index call click

myCheckBox.get(0).click();  // for the first check box
Thread.sleep(2000);
myCheckBox.get(1).click();  // for the second check box
```

or if you want to select on the basis of value then

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='firstValue']")).click();  // for the 1st one
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='secondValue']")).click();  // for the 2st one
```

**UPDATE**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@value='firstValue']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='firstValue']")).click();  // for the 1st one
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: i dont have the number of checkboxes,

Comment: that is why i took it in list first ,taking everything in list java gives each value a index value and in java index starts form 0 so for 1 st check box index is 0,for second check box index is 1 and so on

Comment: i got this error : ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: hi i have updated my answer plz look at it i have used a webdriverwait to tell web driver to wait for the element visibility for 30 seconds before throwing any error

Comment: i updated my question with the name of site and my code, including your suggestion, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works-

```
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//label[contains(text(),'First')]/input")).SendKeys("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("selectedNavigationCategoryPath")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Below Code is in C#, Collects all the Checkboxes with the name specified. Then Iterates through each ckeckbox, gets the value attribute, if the attribute is equal to your specified check box, then clicks it and comes out of the loop. Hope this should work.
IList<IWebElement> myCheckBoxs =    driver.FindElements(By.name("selectedNavigationCategoryPath"));

Foreach(IWebElement chkBx in myCheckBoxs)
{
   if(chkBx.GetAttribute("Value")=="Your Desired value")
   {
     chkBx.Click();
     break;
   }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS locator.

```
[name='selectedNavigationCategoryPath'][value='firstValue']
```